# Freshly install windows 10 when you can't access BIOS

Tags: windows-10, installation, nvme

After a botched install of windows 10 due to the system fan failing, I've been unable to access the BIOS, as the recovery short cut doesn't work. Is there any way to force the laptop to boot from a windows 10 install USB without the BIOS? It won't open onto windows as it says there was an installation error and restarts.

I can access the recovery screen by holding the power button thrice but all options are unresponsive except from enter which just restarts the process. It's an nvme ssd.

The windows errors are:
0xc0000001
0xc000000f

Comment: Remove the SSD and try, or, possibly put in a newly formatted drive of any type.

Comment: Most likely this happens because the failed install of Windows 10 has enabled Fast Boot by default and it is now taking precedence during cold boot and you have no ability to restart Windows since it's not loading properly. One way to solve this is to remove the battery and long press Power-ON button for 30 seconds to clear any static, put in the battery again and retry.

Comment: Battery will be non-removable in most new-ish laptops, as opposed to the SSD, which should be user-replaceable with rare exceptions. Removing it will leave booting into UEFI setup as the only option.